# SQL find exact record combination

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, one with routes and one with order delivery data.

I need to choose for each order exact route which has all shops in it, no more no less, order of shops is not important. If I don't have exact route, I don't want to join any route to that order.

```
RouteId    ShopId
------------------------------------
1            111
1            222
2            111
2            222
2            333
3            111
3            222
3            333
3            444

OrderId     ShopId
------------------------------------
11           111
11           222
11           333
12           111
12           222
13           111
13           333
```

I want result set like this

```
OrderId     ShopId   RouteId
------------------------------------
11           111        2
11           222        2
11           333        2
12           111        1
12           222        1
13           111        NULL
13           333        NULL
```

I have around 50k-100k orders so I don't want to use cursors or any other loop if not necessary.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Zoran

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I don't get the down close votes.  It is a clear specific question to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` in order to get into a string value all shops per `OrderId` and per `RouteId`:

```
;WITH RoutesCTE AS (
  SELECT RouteId, 
         (SELECT ShopId 
         FROM routes AS r2
         WHERE r2.RouteId = r1.RouteId
         ORDER BY ShopId
         FOR XML PATH('')) AS RouteShops
  FROM routes AS r1
  GROUP BY RouteId
), OrdersCTE AS (
  SELECT OrderId, ShopId,
         (SELECT ShopId 
         FROM orders AS o2
         WHERE o2.OrderId = o1.OrderId
         ORDER BY ShopId
         FOR XML PATH('')) AS OrderShops
  FROM orders AS o1 
)
SELECT OrderId, ShopId, c2.RouteId
FROM OrdersCTE AS c1
LEFT JOIN RoutesCTE AS c2 ON c1.OrderShops = c2.RouteShops
```

In the above CTEs `RouteShops` and `OrderShops` hold an XML value of all shops per `RouteId` and `OrderId` respectively.

So, for example, `RoutesCTE` returns the following results:

```
RouteId RouteShops
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1       <ShopId>111</ShopId><ShopId>222</ShopId>
2       <ShopId>111</ShopId><ShopId>222</ShopId><ShopId>333</ShopId>
3       <ShopId>111</ShopId><ShopId>222</ShopId><ShopId>333</ShopId><ShopId>444</ShopId>
```

Comparing these two fields we can find exact matches (if any).

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0c41/2)

**Note:** The above query may return more than one route per `OrderId` if the `routes` table contains `RouteId`s having the same combination of `ShopId`s. In this case you have to fiddle with the `RoutesCTE` (including a `ROW_NUMBER` in it for example).

Answer (score 0):

Use of LEFT JOIN put to NULL fields of secondary table (RouteTable) is there's no corrispondence in JOIN clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT O.*, R.RouteId
FROM OrderTable O
LEFT OUTER JOIN RouteTable R
ON O.ShopId = R.ShopId
```

Comment: Please add some description as to why this will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I like the xml answer from Giorgos better but I had started on this

```
select t1.* 
from 
(
select cteS.OrderID, cteR.RouteID, count(*) as count  
  from cteS 
  join cteR 
        on cteS.StoreID = cteR.StoreID 
 group by cteS.OrderID, cteR.RouteID 
) t1
join 
(
select cteS.OrderID, count(*) as count  
  from cteS 
 group by cteS.OrderID 
) t2 
 on t1.OrderID = t2.OrderID 
and t2.count   = t2.count
```

or

```
select OrderID, RouteID 
  from store 
  join route 
        on store.storeID = route.storeID 
except 
select OrderID, RouteID 
  from store 
  full outer join route 
        on store.storeID = route.storeID 
where store.storeID is null or route.storeID is null
```